# processe indicator change layout SAPUI5

Tags: css, sapui5

hello someone can help me with this ? 
I what to change my process indicator  from SAPUI5  to make something like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrztC.png)

the idea is show how much percent are favor about something and how much percent is against 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a custom control like this or added some code to the onAfterRendering event.

```js
  ProgressIndicator.extend("ProgressIndicatorEx", {
    renderer: {},
    onAfterRendering: function() {
      if (ProgressIndicator.prototype.onAfterRendering) {
        ProgressIndicator.prototype.onAfterRendering.apply(this, arguments);
      }

      var percentValue = this.getPercentValue();
      this.$().find("#" + this.getId() + "-bar").html('<span id="' + this.getId() + '-textLeft" class="sapMPIText sapMPITextRight" style="color: #FFF; margin-right:8px">' + percentValue + '%</span>'); 

      var rightBar = this.$().find("#" + this.getId() + "-remainingBar");
      rightBar.html('<span id="' + this.getId() + '-textRight" class="sapMPIText sapMPITextRight" style="color: #FFF">' + (100 - percentValue) + '%</span>');
      rightBar.css("background-color", "#c00")
      rightBar.css("border-color", "#c00")
    }
```

demo: https://jsbin.com/yawiqam/edit?js,output